# Python: How to copy data from snapshot to disk using start_copy_from_url api

Tags: azure, azure-python-sdk

I am using Microsoft Azure SDK for Python in project. I want to copy data from snapshot to disk. For this task I am using readable SASuri of Snapshot and writable SASuri of Disk.

Here is the example I am using to transfer data.

```
blob_client = BlobClient.from_blob_url("https://<writable-SASUri-disk>")
copy_source_url = r"https://<readable-SASUri-snapshot>"
blob_client.start_copy_from_url(copy_source_url, metadata=None, incremental_copy=False,requires_sync=True)
```

And I am getting below error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mdMa.png)

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you share the code in text format and don't post it as an image?

Comment: Please refer again, edited it.

Comment: @Nilesh May I know which snapshot are you using here? Is it Azure VM disk snapshot or blob snapshot?

Comment: Hii @SiddheshDesai it's a Azure VM disk snapshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried the code below to copy my snapshot to disk using blob client copy url by using my SAS URLs, but received an error with limitation like below:-***

**Code:-**

```py
import asyncio
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient

async def copy_snapshot_to_disk():
    # Create a BlobClient object for the writable SAS URI of the disk
    disk_client = BlobClient.from_blob_url("https://valleystrg.blob.core.windows.net/disk/abcd?sp=rw&st=2023-04-03T10:27:36Z&se=2023-04-03T18:27:36Z&spr=https&sv=2021-12-02&sr=b&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxJtcei011QjEcoC7A%3D")
    # Create a BlobClient object for the readable SAS URI of the snapshot
    snapshot_client = BlobClient.from_blob_url("https://valleystrg.blob.core.windows.net/disk/abcd%20(1)?sp=r&st=2023-04-03T10:25:25Z&se=2023-04-03T18:25:25Z&spr=https&sv=2021-12-02&sr=b&sig=xxxxxtEQ3er2SSVWqshkiXJ8CEpn7s68O%2FOjm0%3D")

    # Start the copy operation from the snapshot to the disk
    headers = {"x-ms-copy-source": snapshot_client.url, "x-ms-copy-type": "blob"}
    copy_id = await disk_client.start_copy_from_url(snapshot_client.url, headers=headers, metadata=None, incremental_copy=False, requires_sync=True)

    # Wait for the copy operation to complete
    while True:
        properties = await disk_client.get_blob_properties()
        if properties.copy.status == "success":
            break
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

    # Print the copy operation result
    print("Copy operation status: ", properties.copy.status)

async def main():
    await copy_snapshot_to_disk()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

**Output:**

```
azure.core.exceptions.ResourceExistsError: **The source request body for synchronous copy is too large and exceeds the maximum permissible limit (256MB).**
Time:2023-04-03T10:46:30.3838959Z
ErrorCode:CannotVerifyCopySource
Content: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>CannotVerifyCopySource</Code><Message>The source request body for synchronous copy is too large and exceeds the maximum permissible limit (256MB).
Time:2023-04-03T10:46:30.3838959Z</Message></Error>
```

[image]

> There's a limit of 256 MB using blob client copy url's to copy the
> data to destination path     and Snapshot or Disks are of 1GB and
> greater size so using above method will not work.

As an **alternative** you can **use az copy tool** to copy your snapshot to disk like below:-

**Command:**

```
azcopy copy `"https://valleystrg.blob.core.windows.net/disk/abcd%20(1)?<SAS-Token>" "https://valleystrg.blob.core.windows.net/disk/abcd?<SAS-Token>" --recursive=true`
```

**Output:**

```
INFO: Scanning...
INFO: azcopy: A newer version 10.17.0 is available to download
INFO: Failed to create one or more destination container(s). Your transfers may still succeed if the container already exists.
INFO: Any empty folders will not be processed, because source and/or destination doesn't have full folder support
Job xxxxxxxx-ddb3dd4dc3ec has started
Log file is located at: /home/xxxx/.azcopy/xxxxxxc.log

100.0 %, 1 Done, 0 Failed, 0 Pending, 0 Skipped, 1 Total, 2-sec Throughput (Mb/s): 268.3198

Job xxxxx-ddb3dd4dc3ec summary
Elapsed Time (Minutes): 0.0667
Number of File Transfers: 1
Number of Folder Property Transfers: 0
Total Number of Transfers: 1
Number of Transfers Completed: 1
Number of Transfers Failed: 0
Number of Transfers Skipped: 0
TotalBytesTransferred: 1073742336
Final Job Status: Completed
```

[image]

**Reference:-**

[az storage blob copy start fails when files are larger than 256MB and requires-sync=true - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/656793/az-storage-blob-copy-start-fails-when-files-are-la)